# Django read the same CBV for different urls

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm using TamplateView in my views so that when a user is logged in, it will be redirect to his home page.

I have two apps: app_manager(responsible for login and sign up) and app_user where we can found all the functionalities of the user.

app_manager.views:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("app_user:switcher_user", args=(slugify(username_instance),)))
```

app_user.views:

```
def switcher_user(request, username):
    print(username)
    qs = User.objects.filter(username=username)
    print(qs)
    if not qs.exists():
        print("user not found")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_user:access_denied'))
    else:
        print("user already exists")
        return user_index.as_view()(request)

class user_index(LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView):
    print("this is from user_index")
    template_name = "app_user/user_index.html"
    model = User
    context_object_name = 'user'


class ProfilView(LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView):
    template_name = "app_user/user_profil.html"

class GroupsView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    template_name = "app_user/user_groups.html"
```

app_user.urls:

```
app_name ="app_user"

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/', views.switcher_user, name='switcher_user'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/profil', views.ProfilView.as_view(), name='user_profil'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/groups', views.GroupsView.as_view(), name='user_groups'),
```

In my app_user application, I have a template folder where we can find all the html page for this type of user. In my base.html:

```
<li> <a href="{% url 'app_user:user_profil' username=user.username %}">Profil</a></li>

<li> <a href="{% url 'app_user:user_groups' username=user.username %}">Groups</a></li>
```

The problem here is, when I click on Profil or Groups to go to the profil page or the groups page, I get the correct url in the browser address bar but the wrong html file. It always read the same view which is switcher_user and then user_index and bring me the same page "user_index.html".!!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't terminate your regexes.

```
re_path(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$', ...)
```